# Xcode Install prev Swift version

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, eureka-forms

I have a Swift 3.2 application that I am preparing to upgrade to Swift 4 with. Over the last week Xcode got automatically upgrade and the Swift version has been changed to 3.3 with no option to move back to 3.2

This would be OK, however the Eureka pod fails with the following error

```
 type 'Section' does not conform to protocol 'RangeReplaceableCollection'
```

This is a error that occurred with previous versions of Eureka and specific 3.2 build was created to fix. The trunk build works on Swift 4. However both the trunk and 3.2 branches fail on 3.3

I can't upgrade to 4 until this error has been resolved. Is there a way to install a previous version of Swift, ie 3.2, on Xcode so that I can move beyond this.

all thoughts welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply download the last version from Xcode that supports Swift 3.2 from your Apple Developer account at https://developer.apple.com/download/more/